# Is there any other way apart from WMI to get genuine window OS status?

Tags: c#

WMI class `SoftwareLicensingProduct` give me a way to get `LicenseStatus' for window operating system.

```
public static bool IsWindowsActivated()
{
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

SelectQuery searchQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE ApplicationID = '55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f' and LicenseStatus = 1");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, searchQuery);

using (ManagementObjectCollection obj = searcherObj.Get())
{
    return obj.Count > 0;
}
```

}

Question 1. Is the WMI class available for all window OS. (Window XP+)?

Question 2. Is there other way to get the same?

Thanks!

Comment: WMI has been a part of NET since 1.1; so it is widely available.  Lots of the Windows related info originates from the registry but often encoded in some form or another.  Not sure where WAT is located

Comment: A documentation in here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692772(v=technet.10)

Comment: What's wrong with WMI?  It's very powerful and flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1. Is the WMI class available for all window OS. (Window
>   XP+)?**

As pointed out in the comments

[Troubleshooting and Tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692772(v=technet.10))

No all *WMI* functions aren't available on all version of windows, you will have to check case by case

---

> **Question 2. Is there other way to get the same?**

There are no BCL ways to do this apart from *WMI*

However you could probably P/Invoke *Win32 Apis* for this sort of thing if you felt the need. if it exists in *WMI* then it most likely as a *Win32 Ap*i counterpart

[SLGetApplicationInformation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/slpublic/nf-slpublic-slgetapplicationinformation)

> Gets information about the specified application.

---

Though my spidy senses tell me that you cant query *WMI* for something, for which you will probably find the same problem in the *Win32 Api*